# Complex Analysis and Polytopes

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Could someone please explain why the following is true?

Suppose we are computing the Taylor coefficient of $z^{tA}$ in
$$\frac{1}{1-z^{A_1}} \frac{1}{1-z^{A_2}} \cdots \frac{1}{1-z^{A_n}} \frac{1}{1-z} $$ 
where all $A_k, A \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why is this equivalent to finding
$$\text{Res} \left( \frac{z^{-tA-1}}{(1-z^{A_1})(1-z^{A_2}) \cdots (1 - z^{A_n})(1-z)}, z=0 \right)? $$

And a further question, why is that equal to 
$$\text{Res} \left( \frac{ z^{-tA} - 1}{ (1-z^{A_1})(1-z^{A_2}) \cdots (1 - z^{A_n})(1-z)z}, z=0 \right) +1? $$

The author of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306035.pdf entirely glosses over this step, saying it's "clearly" true...

Comment: The residue of a Laurent series at $z=0$ is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, but in this case $z^{-1}$ doesn't bring me any closer to finding the coefficient in the preceding expression. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: As for the "further question," note that you missed a factor of $z$ the author added in the denominator.

Comment: If you have an analytic function $f(z)$ with Taylor series near $0$ then obviously the coefficient of $z^n$ in the Taylor series  is the residue of $z^{-n-1}f(z)$ at zero since it is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ of the latter